# Assets for Unit-Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am migrating some tests from instrumentation to unit-tests ( the new ones that came with 1.1 ) - And now I am facing the problem that I find no way to supply the tests with files ( data that I need to test if it gets parsed correctly )
Anyone knows a way to do this?
Unfortunately for the android asset stuff I have no context and this also does not work:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("src.sgf")
```

The above is null with the file in:

```
src/test/assets/src.sgf
```

Interestingly AndroidStudio recognizes the asset - when I control click on the src.sgf in the code it brings me to the right file.

Comment: This is possible. Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35690692/3032209) answer

Comment: Yea it is possible - but there was a bug at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you are looking for resources being accessible from your unit-tests environment.

It is an official issue of android build tools gradle plugin version 1.1.

You can find work around for this issue in this following thread [Test resources not found from unit test](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=136013#c33)